# aws s3 time not synced, authentication failure using awsaccesskeyid

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ntp

Had the issue of awsaccesskey and awssecretkey not authenticating,

```
aws s3 ls
```

gave 
`An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.`

So,  I tried syncing the time with my local time, which was incorrect. Even after the sync, the issue persisted.
I am in the region of ap-south-1 Mumbai my time was set correctly but the error still occurred.

I tried launching an instance and `timedatectl` gave this,

```
      Local time: Sat 2018-09-08 08:25:06 UTC
  Universal time: Sat 2018-09-08 08:25:06 UTC
        RTC time: Sat 2018-09-08 08:25:05
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

The server is also in ap-south-1 so I dont get why the local time is (UTC, +0000)

Trying to set my system clock to a similar time (UTC, +0000) results in this,

```
                      Local time: Sat 2018-09-08 20:09:46 +00
              Universal time: Sat 2018-09-08 20:09:46 UTC
                    RTC time: Sat 2018-09-08 20:09:46
                   Time zone: Atlantic/Azores (+00, +0000)
   System clock synchronized: yes systemd-timesyncd.service active: no
             RTC in local TZ: no
```

I've tried adjusting my machine's time to everything I can think of but still am unable to fix this error. I also chose to add servers from my region to ntpd.conf

```
server 3.in.pool.ntp.org
server 3.asia.pool.ntp.org
server 0.asia.pool.ntp.org
```

But this didn't help either.
Local Machine is running Ubuntu 18.04LTS, Instance is Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Is there something I'm missing about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show the output from `ntpq -pcrv`

Comment: *"The server is also in ap-south-1 so I dont get why the local time is (UTC, +0000)"*  Note that the "local" time on any correctly-configured server is *always* UTC.  When you see `Z` in a timestamp, that's UTC.  S3 expects the client to know how to derive the correct current time in UTC, which the client can only do if *both* its clock is accurate *and* the client knows its current clock offset from UTC.

Comment: For some reason, in the two attempts you made to show times, above, there is a ~12 hour discrepancy between one and the other. Did you notice that? 0800 vs 2000.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or why this was caused, but changing the time manually-in the bios and going into system settings and entering the hours and minutes fixed it. Should've tried that first.

Thanks for the help.